# I have 3 up votes on my answer but the total shows as 22 why?

Tags: discussion

I just answered some question and got 3 upvotes on it.
It should sum up to 30 but why is it 22?

Comment: Looks like you hit the rep cap for the day.

Answer (score 2):

You have reached the repuation cap - 200 a day from upvotes only.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) for details.

Comment: So is it that if I have 200 reputaion per day I can't go above that? After 200 each time there is a upvote do I get +2?

Comment: After 200 (from upvotes), you don't get **any** more. The 2 is probably because you lost 2 rep earlier in the day (just looked - due to a downvote).

Comment: Oh I was not knowing this . But still if answers are accepted I get +15?

Comment: @Gopi - yes. Please read the link I posted for all the details.

Comment: Sorry for bothering I am being a bit lazy :) Anyways thanks for the info.